# Nest can't resolve dependency, but it's definitely there

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have a weird behaviour. Nest is complaining about a missing dependency in a service, but only if that service is Injected by multiple other services

**cleaning.module.ts**

```
@Module({
imports: [
 //Just a few repos
],
providers: [
    ServicesService,
    ...
    AreasService,
    RoomsService,
    ...
],
controllers: [
...
],
exports: [
    ServicesService,
    ...
    AreasService,
    RoomsService,
    ...
]})
```

**services.module.ts**, **areas.module.ts** and **rooms.module.ts** are basically the same

```
@Module({
  imports: [CleaningModule],
  providers: [],
  controllers: [],
  exports: []
})
```

**rooms.service.ts**

```
constructor(@InjectRepository(Room) private readonly repo: Repository<Room>, private areasService: AreasService) { }
```

**services.service.ts**

```
constructor(@InjectRepository(Service) private readonly repo: Repository<Service>, ... private roomsService: RoomsService) { }
```

With this, I get the following error:

> ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RoomsService (RoomRepository, ?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [1] is available in the CleaningModule context.

So, it's missing `AreasService` somehow. Which is clearly provided by the `CleaningModule`.

But the weird thing is, if I remove the injection of the `RoomsService` in the `ServicesService` constructor, then everything works just fine. And I don't have the slightest idea why this is the case...

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any kind of [circular dependency](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency)? Have you tried `forwardRef()`?

Comment: @SoroushAhrari i dont see, how that would be possible. All providers imported are in the CleaningModule and only the CleaningModule gets imported by the component specific modules...

Comment: regarding the provided details, `AreasService` is imported in `RoomsService` and `RoomsService` in `ServicesService`, so have you imported `ServicesService` anywhere else which finally creates a chain to `AreasServices`? So I think when you remove `RoomsService` from `ServicesService`, it breaks the chain and everything works fine. this is the only thing that comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

[Based on the error](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/common-errors#cannot-resolve-dependency-error) it seems like you have a circular file import going on from your `roo.service.ts` to your `area.service.ts`. This could be several files deep like `room.service.ts` imports `area.service.ts` that another that imports another that imports another that finally imports `room.service.ts` again or it could be the use of barrel files. If this truly is a [circular dependency](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency) (room uses area which uses room) then you need to use `@Inject(forwardRef(() => OtherService))`. Otherwise, you need to figure out a way to avoid the circular import

Comment: Yes, it was in fact a several files deep circular dependency which i could resolve.